# Получение значений по заранее неизвестному ключу в JSON (Java Gson)

Tags: java, json, gson

Занимаюсь поддержкой тестового кода Java по обработке запросов с сервера при помощи библиотеки Gson.
Все было хорошо, до недавнего времени.
Входные данные: есть массив из 28000+ строк, приведу часть JSON с интересующей частью:

```
{
  "status": {
    "code": code,
    "message": "message"
  },
  "data": {
    "datas": [
      {
        "id": idHere,
        "date_gmt": "2020-08-04T07:01:47",
        "title": "title1",
        "status": "publish",
        "data_category": [
          263,
          495,
          492,
          68
        ],
        "is-bonus-data": false,
        "data-poster": "link here",
        "data-preview-sprite": "link here",
        "sprite": "link here",
        "data-links": {
          "3D 180 01_trailer": "link here",
          "3D 180 02_trailer": "link here",
          "3D 180 03_trailer": "link here",
          "3D 180 04_trailer": "link here",
          "3D 180 05_trailer": "link here"
        },
        "data-positions": [
          "data-positions1",
          "data-positions2"
        ],
        ...
}
```

Данный JSON описан в классе, и при получении все нормально парситься, но...

В последнее время в поле "data-links" стали приходить объекты с ключами, отличающиеся от "стандартных" - "3D 180 01_trailer_001", "3D 360 03_trailer" и т.д. По началу было принято решение добавлять эти ключи как поле класса, и собственно парсить еще и по ним, но сам класс data-links уже раздулся до невероятных размеров.

Класс, который описывает

```
public class DataLinks {
@SerializedName("3D 180 01_trailer")
@Expose
private String _3D18001Trailer;

@SerializedName("3D 180 02_trailer")
@Expose
private String _3D18002Trailer;

@SerializedName("3D 180 03_trailer")
@Expose
private String _3D1803KTrailer;

@SerializedName("3D 180 04_trailer")
@Expose
private String _3D1804KTrailer;

@SerializedName("3D 180 05_trailer")
@Expose
private String _3D18005Trailer;
}
```

Вопрос: как обеспечить тестам "вытаскивать" значения по ключам, которые заранее неизвестны?
Смотрел ответы google, самые разные, где люди приводят примеры, самый подходящий был здесь: [Как разобрать динамический ключ JSON во вложенном результате JSON](https://coderoad.ru/7304002/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87-JSON-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-JSON), но код начинает плеваться эксепшенами при попытке адаптации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать `java.util.Map`:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    @Data
    static class Test {

        @SerializedName("data-links")
        private Map<String, String> dataLinks;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json =
                "{" +
                "\"data-links\": {" +
                "\"3D 180 01_trailer\": \"link here\"," +
                "\"3D 180 02_trailer\": \"link here\"," +
                "\"3D 180 03_trailer\": \"link here\"," +
                "\"3D 180 04_trailer\": \"link here\"," +
                "\"3D 180 05_trailer\": \"link here\"" +
                "}" +
                "}";
        Test test = new Gson().fromJson(json, Test.class);
        System.out.println(
                test.dataLinks.entrySet().stream()
                        .map(e -> e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue())
                        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
    }

}
```

Результат:

```
3D 180 01_trailer: link here
3D 180 02_trailer: link here
3D 180 03_trailer: link here
3D 180 04_trailer: link here
3D 180 05_trailer: link here
```